# What is Grails' default propagation for transaction=false?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-transactions

> Setting `transactional` to `false` you disable automatic Spring managed transaction demarcation for every method in the service. [(c)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Services/transactional.html)

Am I right it is equivalent to an explicit @Transactional(propagation=[Propagation.SUPPORTS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS))? Or transaction=false cannot be expressed via @Transaction exactly?

Grails 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I think one difference is that if you are using Spring's `@Transactional` the methods will be proxied even if you use `Propagation.SUPPORTS` while a `transactional=false` declaration will prevent that.